# ClickOnce deployment error - access to the path is denied

Tags: clickonce

I have a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application that I'm deploying to a network path using ClickOnce deployment. After the application is deployed to a network location, I use the ClickOnce HTML page to launch the installation process. I am successfully able to download and install the application.

However, my users are not able to download and install the application. When a user navigates to the ClickOnce HTML page and clicks to begin the installation process, the following error message is received:

---

```
ERROR SUMMARY
        Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
        * Activation of http://software.mycompany.com/myapp/myapp.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
                    + Downloading file://dev/webs/software/myapp/myapp.application did not succeed.


        * [4/5/2010 1:56:59 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
                    - Downloading file://dev/Webs/software/myapp/myapp.application did not succeed.
```

---

All signs point to this being a security issue. So, I've done the following:

- Ensured that "Everyone" had read access to the files that were being deployed as part of my project
- Ensured that "Everyone" had read access to the network location where the application was deployed (//dev/webs/software/myapp)
- Ensured that "Everyone" had read access to the [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) path where the ClickOnce HTML page is located

In each of these cases, I've made no progress in getting the application to successfully deploy via ClickOnce.

Again, the odd thing is that I am able to successfully walk through the process of downloading and installing the application. It's my users, though, that need the ability to download and install the application.

I've looked extensively on the web for answers, but there hasn't been much. I'd like to resolve the issue without "re-installing" or "rigging" anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are publishing your files to a network location that is only exposed to your clients via a web server. In that case, in the publish tab of your project properties, your Installation Folder URL is incorrect (or has not been specified). You can see that by looking at the error message. The user is accessing a http:// URL, but ClickOnce is trying to download a file from a file:// URL, which the client probably can't access. You should set the Installation Folder URL to `http://software.mycompany.com/myapp/` so that ClickOnce knows from where to download the application.

Comment: This was definitely the issue.  I have since updated the deployment location on the deplyoment tab and all is good.  

Here's some info which may help folks who are having deployment issues:

1) If you're deploying to an UNC path, make sure you verify your users' sharing AND security permissions on the folder.

2) If you're deploying to an http location, make sure you verify your users' permissions to this link.

Answer (score 0):

Do your users have read and execute rights to the folder or just read? Try giving them privileges for that. If that doesn't work, try setting one to have write access and see if that works for them.

It seems like we had to do that when I was messing around with the permission stuff. I couldn't just set it to read access.