# ClickOnce error message 'Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config' is denied'

Tags: winforms, clickonce, .net-4.5, access-denied, machine.config

Our ClickOnce application has been working fine. However, one of our users gets the following error:

```
+ Configuration system failed to initialize
+ An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config' is denied. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config)
+ Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config' is denied.
```

Our `Installation Folder URL` appears to be fine as per the Stack Overflow article *[ClickOnce deployment error - access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746927)*, and the discussion *[Access denied to machine.config on Win7 x64](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst912_Access-denied-to-machine-config-on-Win7-x64.aspx)* isn't really clear what permissions should be checked, e.g. NETWORK SERVICE? And finally [this MSDN article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/b31432bc-5025-45a7-91aa-f96644ce4458) refers to changing passwords which doesn't make sense to me.

What might be causing the issue? And perhaps what permissions might be required?

Another Stack Overflow post, *[ClickOnce and configuration for a C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018075)*, seems to refer to this issue, but asks a different question (trying to avoid using `Machine.config`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reinstalled .NET 4.5 on the user's machine and it now works fine.